# Why cant i kill the task remotly through my .bat Script? [solved]

Tags: windows-command-prompt, windows-server-2022, task

I want to write a .bat Script, where i want to kill a task remotly from my pc on my windows server 2022.

When i try the command "taskkill /u Administrator /p mypassword /s 192.168.178.226 /im Cluster_Manager.exe /f /t"

it says:

Error: The process with pid 4664 (child process of pid 2384) could not be terminated.
Cause: internal error

Firewall is already disabled.

I have no idea what it could be...

[Edit]

I used the PSExec tool form "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec". The tool solved the problem for me.

Comment: We have to Debug your Issue : (1) Directly try this command on the server itself , to check what it shows. (2) Try tasklist in the command to check the output. (3) Try terminating some other Process eg notepad , to check the output. You can include all that Debug Data in your Post , which will enable troubleshooting your Issue further !

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already got the solution for my problem. I used the PSExec tool form "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec". That helped for me :)

Comment: Great that you were able to solve your problem, but please don't edit the solution into your question. This way the question stays in the system forever as "unsolved". Instead, post your solution as an answer and accept it. You will even get some reputation for it.

Comment: I think the Solution is a Workaround or a Co-incidence , we will not know why the Original Command did not work. Oh Well , OP has got a Working Alternative , hence no way to figure out the Original Issue now. @GeraldSchneider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got the solution for my problem. I used the PSExec tool form "learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec". That helped for me :)